# How to create error message when negative number is entered in Java factorial

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, factorial

I need to modify this code so that and error message is displayed when a negative number is entered. I know and else statement has to fit in I just can figure out where.

Comment: I suggest that you check each of the steps in the pseudocode. Find which line of Java code implements each step. You should be able to find a line that isn't implemented in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all you need to do is check for incorrect input to throw an exception.

```
public static void numberFactorial() {  
    System.out.println("Option 2 selected, enter a number: "); 
    int number = sc.nextInt(); 
    if(number < 0){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException()
    }
    // ... rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void numberFactorial() {  

    System.out.println("Option 2 selected, enter a number: "); 
    int number = sc.nextInt();

    // here you can check for negative number
    if(number >= 0){
         System.out.println("The factorial is: " + number + " ");  


        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) 
       {
            factorial *= i;


            if ((number - 1) > 0)   
            {
                System.out.print("x" + (number - i) + " ");

            }

            System.out.println("=" + factorial); 


        }
    }else{
      System.out.println("Negative number is not allowed, entered number is: " + number + " ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain **in words** how your code solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the best way but,

```
public static void numberFactorial() { 

System.out.println("Option 2 selected, enter a number: ");
boolean isNegative =true;
int number;

while (isNegative) {

number = sc.nextInt(); 
if(number < 0 ){
 System.out.println("Negative Number Detected, please enter your number again");
}else {
 break; 
}



System.out.println("The factorial is: " + number + " ");  


for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) 


{
        factorial *= i;


        if ((number - 1) > 0)   
        {
            System.out.print("x" + (number - i) + " ");

        }

        System.out.println("=" + factorial); 


    }
}
```